# Store '\abc\def\fg.jpg' Problem in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store relative path of a document into a MySQL table. The problem is that when I insert a string of this form:

```
$urlPath ='\abc\def\fg.jpg'
```

into the relevant column, what I get is, I have all the slash `'\'` strip off, with an unknown symbol in front of all the text. So the result in the MySQL table is something like this:

```
'(weird symbol)abcdeffg.jpg'
```

As you can see, this kind of data is useless. Any idea how to fix this?

Edit: I tried  `$urlPath ="\\abc\\def\\fg.jpg"` and `$urlPath ='\\abc\\def\\fg.jpg'`, still I got gibberish..

Comment: What happens if you try $urlPath = '\\abc\\def\\fg.jpg'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape it twice, first for PHP because the \ character has a special meaning:

From the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single):

> To specify a literal backslash before
> a single quote, or at the end of the
> string, double it (\)

```
$urlPath ='\\abc\\def\\fg.jpg';
```

Then you need to escape it again for MySQL because the literal string now contains 's which also has special meaning to MySQL.

> [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) calls
> MySQL's library function
> mysql_real_escape_string, which
> prepends backslashes to the following
> characters: \x00, \n, \r, , ', " and
> \x1a.

```
$databaseUrlPath = mysql_real_escape_string($urlPath);
```

If you don't want to depend on MySQL, you can use [addslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) instead:

> Returns a string with backslashes
> before characters that need to be
> quoted in database queries etc. These
> characters are single quote ('),
> double quote ("), backslash () and
> NUL (the NULL byte).

```
$databaseUrlPath = addslashes($urlPath);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use mysql_real_escape_string( ) to escape special characters in your string before using this string in an insert/update query.

The backslashes are special characters in PHP and MySQL so they need to be escaped at the both levels -- PHP and MySQL.

Comment: I would prefer a pure PHP solution-- instead of the one that tie to MySQL

Comment: "pure php solution"? mysql_real_escape_string() is a php function.

Comment: Sorry..what I mean is, I want the code that works even without any MySQL connection opened. In your case here, you need MySQL connection to open in order to use that function

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$urlPath ='\\abc\\def\\fg.jpg'
```

Comment: Note the use of single quotes - if you tried double quotes, it wouldn't have worked.

Comment: Still it doesn't work, I am running on Windows... does that make a diff?

Answer (score 1):

> what I mean is, I want the code that works even without any MySQL connection opened.

Sorry, that's not possible: you do actually need a connection to do proper escaping, because escaping methods are connection-specific:

1. In some character sets, the 0x27 and 0x5C bytes (`'` and `\`) may be part of a multi-byte character, in which case backslash-escaping it will generate the wrong results and may actually *introduce* an SQL injection possibility! So you have to know the connection's character set to escape the right `'` *characters* rather than *bytes*.
2. If the server is using the configuration option `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` to be ANSI SQL compliant, backslash-escaping is the wrong thing to do and won't protect against SQL injection.

So you do need `mysql_real_escape_string` and a connection object to correctly escape a string literal. This isn't usually a problem because the right time to `mysql_real_escape_string` something is just the moment before it goes into the executed query. You shouldn't be passing around mysql-escaped strings otherwise.

If you don't use/support the ANSI options, and either you're sure your database connection will always be using a single-byte character set or you're sure non-ASCII characters will never appear, you can safely use `addslashes` instead, which does not require a connection.

But better is to use [parameterised queries](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) so you don't have to think about any of this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

the \ character is an escape character for many programming and scripting languages, including php.

You'll have to use double \ to escape it. The same goes if you want to enter symbols like ' " and so on into a database, or use " within a string, something like $mystr = "I can have \" in my string";